# Type of convergence of a Cauchy sequence of functions on a complete metric space?

Tags: convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a Cauchy sequence of functions defined on a complete metric space $E$. Then $f_n \to f$ on $E$. What is the type of this convergence? Is it pointwise?

Comment: What do you mean by _a Cauchy sequence of functions_?

Comment: I mean: $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N$ such that $\forall m, n \geq N$, $\forall x \in E$ implies $|f_m(x) - f_n(x)| < \epsilon$

Comment: If  it's Cauchy according to some metric, then it'll be convergent according to that metric (in your case, that means uniform convergence, since the norm is the supremum norm)

Comment: so that means: $\forall \epsilon > 0, \forall x \in E, \exists N$ such that $|f_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$ ?

Comment: Swap the quantifiers for $N$ and $x$ -- it's uniform convergence, not only pointwise.

Answer (score 0):

Depends. Is $f_n : E \to \mathbb{R}$? Is E an function space?

If it's the first then yes it's the pointwise convergence ie $f_n(x) \to f(x) \forall x \in E$.

If you mean the second (E is an function space and $f_n \in E$) then no, it's a normal convergence ($\forall \epsilon>0 \exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that if $N \leq n$ then $d(f_n,f) < \epsilon$).

Comment: It is actually the first case. Btw, what is a function space?

Comment: Function space is a metric space where the elements are functions instead of (for example) numbers. 

So take for example $\Lambda$ to be the set of all continue functions f so that $f([0,1]) \to [-1,1]$ and define the distance between f and g by d(f,g) = $max(f(x)-g(x))$ with $x \in [0,1]$. This would be a function space